# StackView item not aligning to the left

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I want my both "bubbles" be aligned to the left.
They are in a stackView with the symbol and the mailLabel.
For some reason shorter text always aligns right.
I tried all distribution settings in the stackView already.

[image: The upper box should be aligned left]

[image: Settings stackview]

Comment: did you try to remove leading constraints from the message body and the stack view and add leading constraints between the message body and the message image

Comment: Yes, there is a contraint between the bubble and the image. And the same distance is set as spacing in the stack view. Same result.

Comment: what is the constraints of body label inside round view ??

Comment: Add an empty UIView in the stack view after the bubble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference ... when you post a "layout" image, it is very helpful to expand the complete hierarchy, including **all** of the constraints.

I'm assuming your horizontal stack view's Trailing is constrained to the Trailing of the `Content View`. That tells auto-layout to keep the stack view the ***full width** of the content view.

To keep your "bubbles" left-aligned in the Horizontal Stack View, set `Distribution: Fill`, then constrain its Trailing to be **less than or equal** to the Content View's Trailing.

Assuming you used the "standard" way of setting constraints in IB - where the Content View Trailing is constrained to the Stack View Trailing, it's "reversed" and should be **greater than or equal**.

So, your constraints probably look very close to this:

[image]

and should be changed to this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In code you can always do:

```
yourStackView.alignment = .leading
```